# select dynamic tag name by xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml with three types possible of child like this

```
1:
<root>
   <child1>
2:
<root>
   <child2>
3:
<root>
   <child3>
```

I want to get child's tag name of each xml by using xpath select.
what xpath syntax should be?

I tried many but cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use:
`name(/*/*)`

`name()` function or `local-name()` can be used to get the name of an element. `local-name()` removes the prefix part though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "concrete" child tags with the following xpath:

```
//root/*[starts-with(name(), 'child')]
```

since all the tags you are interested in start with 'child', this will get you the correct nodes in each case.

To print the tag-name you can go for the solution of @Lingamurthy CS:

just use `name(yournode)` or `local-name(yournode)`

This assumes that your example is correct and the tags you're interested in are direct children of root.

Comment: This does **not** return the node's **name**. Moreover, it assumes that the name is partially known. I would have thought `child1`, `child2`, etc. are just examples.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you are of course right! edited my answer. Regarding the assumption: That's why I explicitly stated this in my answer because it is a bit too vague in the question.